# What's the recommended way in Symfony of taking JSON data and populating an entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

If I'm receiving JSON data in a request (say an API type interface), what's the Symfony recommended way of populating an entity. It seems to me the options are:

- Use the form component – passing the decoded JSON as an array to the `submit()` method.
- Use the Serializer to deserialize.

It seems to me the issue with using the serializer is that you need to manually do data transformation (and validation, though simple).

Using the form component feels kind of hacky and a also uses a lot of functionality that isn't touched/needed.

Are there other options (built into Symfony or other bundles/packages)? Or is one of these the recommended way?

(I realize this is at least partially an opinion based question...)

Comment: Might want to skim through the docs for the [api-platform](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform).  It illustrates one rather extreme approach to api's which may or may not be a good fit for your projects.  The creator is also an active member of the Symfony core team.  At the other end of the spectrum, don't rule just writing a custom transformer of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned - this is a pretty opinionated issue to deal with. The options you've been considering are the two common ways of handling it:

1. Just go with the `Form` component - need to create a FormType, adds some performance overhead (not significant in most cases). As a bonus - it gives you all the Form perks like not allowing extra fields, ability to use Form events etc.
2. Use `Serializer` + `Validator` - a "skinny" option in terms of components employed, a bit more verbose, doesn't come with Form perks

I'd say that there is really nothing wrong with using forms to handle deserialization and validation in one go.

Have a look at the sample action code below. Note that it is using the `FOSRestBundle` `View` class to handle responses. It simply takes in a json encoded entity data and either creates a new entity based on it or updates an existing one.

```
 public function sampleAction(SampleEntity $sampleEntity, Request $request) {

    //Is it a new or existing entity?
    $statusCode = $sampleEntity->getId() ? 200 : 201;

    //Load our form with the entity provided by the route loader
    $form = $this->createForm(SampleEntityType::class, $sampleEntity);

    //Decode the actual input and make Form component to populate an entity for us
    $formData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $form->submit($formData);

    //Validation is as simple as this
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($sampleEntity);
        $em->flush();
        return View::create($form, $statusCode);
    }

    return View::create($form->getErrors(true, false), 400);
}
```